# How can I pass a list to a function?

Tags: python, function

I am using `nameparser` function to pass a column to the function and to come out with a column.

I am running this:

```
from nameparser import HumanName
name = HumanName("JONATHON FURBER")
name.first
```

But instead of do this one by one, I want to do it for a long list of names. How can I do?

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Are you using https://pypi.org/project/nameparser/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the nameparser (https://pypi.org/project/nameparser/), you can declare a list of people, and loop through them to pass each person into the nameparser.HumanName and print out their first names:

```
from nameparser import HumanName

people = ["JONATHON FURBER",
          "Dr. Juan Q. Xavier de la Vega III (Doc Vega)"
          ]

for person in people:
    name = HumanName(person)
    print(name.first)
```

Returning:

```
JONATHON
Juan
```

Or perhaps you prefér having all the first names stored as a list. This can be done with a list comprehension:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp

first_names = [HumanName(person).first
               for person in people
               ]

pp(first_names)
```

Returning:

```
['JONATHON', 'Juan']
```

Addition: you asked in the comment how to combine the results, so you could for example zip the people with their first names inside tuples and store them with a list comprehension:

```
combined_list = [(fn, person) for fn, person in zip(first_names, people)]
pp(combined_list)
```

Returning:

```
[('JONATHON', 'JONATHON FURBER'),
 ('Juan', 'Dr. Juan Q. Xavier de la Vega III (Doc Vega)')]
```

Save it to a file:

```
with open("people.txt", "w") as wf:
    for person in combined_list:
        wf.write(person[0] + ', ' + person[1])
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav Rasmussen. This is awesome. Thank you very much!! May i know how then can I join back to the original input list and export it out?

Comment: It is my pleasure :) If you found this answer useful, please consider to upvote it and mark as correct answer. To join the two lists, you can use the zip() function and create a dictionary or list of tuples.

Comment: I am happy to hear it :)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **yes, you can in python call a function with a list**.

Let us dig more into your problem. I assume that you are using the Python library [nameparser](https://nameparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) which seems like it does not understand a vector-call like in matlab. So you probably should just loop over your list of names to be parsed.